# Ruby on rails project deploy to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I have a ruby on rails project. It runs successfully on my PC with command "rails s". So I decided to deploy it to AWS using Capistrano. Server side, I am using Puma + Nginx + mysql stack. (I am following this guide: https://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/)

I got error when I run "cap production deploy":

```
Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy2@111.21.5.197: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...e bootstrap.min": expected "{", was ""
(sass):6648
```

I found out it was the file app/assets/stylesheets/application.css causes the error. In this file, I have only one line:

```
*= require bootstrap.min
```

I think it is correct. Because the app can run on my PC.
If I remove this line, there will be no error when I run "cap production deploy". The app can deploy to the server and run on the server. But no CSS for all the web pages. I am basically new to ruby on rails. So I don't know the details after all these files. Does anyone can suggest what should I do in order to make my app deploy to the server successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your stylesheet to `application.scss` (note the **scss** extension) and make sure it contains this line:

```
//= require bootstrap.min
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I have spent days google the solution.